# Show that $\frac{az+b}{cz+d}\in \mathbb H$.

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry

Let $a,b,c,d\in \mathbb R$ s.t. $ad-bc=1$. Let $$\mathbb H=\{z=x+iy\in \mathbb C\mid y>0\}.$$
Show that $$\gamma =\frac{az+b}{cz+d}\in \mathbb H$$
for $z\in \mathbb H$.

If $c=0$ or $d=0$, I proved it. But in the case where $c,d\neq 0$, I just get $$\gamma =\frac{a}{c}-\frac{1}{c(cz+d)}.$$

Is there an easy way to conclude ? (excepted the hard calculation).

Comment: It's not true for all $z$. Do you mean for $z\in\mathbb H$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Yes, for $z\in \mathbb H$. Sorry

Comment: Tangentially, I'm a little surprised there isn't a modular-groups tag.  I guess there's a modular-forms tag, though.

Comment: The trick is to note that it it is a mobius function that sends the real line to the real line. So all you need to know is, where does it send $i$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One trick:

This function sends the real line to the real line, as does the inverse function. So the image of $\mathbb H$ must be path-connected and not cross the real line, so this function must send $\mathbb H$ to one half of the plane. Now you only really need to know where it sends $i$:

$$\frac{b+ai}{d+ci}=\frac{(b+ai)(d-ci)}{d^2+c^2} = \frac{bd+ac + (ad-bc)i}{c^2+d^2}= \frac{bd+ac + i}{c^2+d^2}\in\mathbb H$$

Answer (score 4):

$$\gamma=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}\cdot\frac{c\overline z+d}{c\overline z+d}=\frac{ac|z|^2+adz+bc\overline z+bd}{|cz+d|^2}$$

The imaginary part of the above, with $\;z=x+iy\;$ ,  is

$$\frac{(ad-bc)y}{|cz+d|^2}=\frac y{|cz+d|^2}>0$$

Answer (score 1):

If $\gamma=\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$ is an invertible matrix with real entries, then
$$ \Im(\gamma z)=\frac{\det(\gamma)\Im(z)}{|cz+d|^2} $$
as you can verify by a direct computation. So in particular if $\det(\gamma)=1$ and $z\in\mathbb{H}$, then $\gamma z\in \mathbb{H}$.